# Multiple Conditions using CASE WHEN with IN and LIKE Operators to Categories Data

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking to categorize data using the last 4 digits of the 'number' column (data type: NUMBER). I can't seem to get it work and I can't find work around on SOF so I'm wondering is there a way to do this in a clean method?

```
select 
case 
when number like in ('%0000', '%1510', '%1511', '%1698', '%1835') then 'CRI'
when number like in ('%1837', '%1838', '%1839') then 'CRE'
when number like in ('%1716', '%1720') then 'Personal'
when number like in ('%1885') then 'RBC'
when number like in ('%1645', '%1920', '%3821') then 'SLC'
when number like in ('%1780', '%1782') then 'OLS'
end as SEGMENT
from TableA;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `in` with `substr()`:

```
select (case when substr(number, -4) in ('0000', '1510', '1511', '1698', '835') then 'CRI'
             when substr(number, -4) in ('1837', '1838', '1839') then 'CRE'
             . . .
        end) as SEGMENT
from TableA;
```

You could also express this using `regexp_like()`:

```
select (case when regexp_like(number, '(0000|1510|1511|1698|1835)$') then 'CRI'
             when regexp_like(number, '(1837|1838|1839)$') then 'CRE'
             . . .
        end) as SEGMENT
```